# How can I visually select, then execute shell commands directly in vim?

Tags: bash, shell, vim

When writing bash scripts in vim, it would be useful to be able to selectively run only a few lines from the script, e.g. if I have some script

```
#! /bin/bash

# more commands

mkdir /tmp/test_dir
echo "some output to STDOUT"
touch /tmp/test_dir/new_file

# more commands
```

say I just want to execute this part of the script

```
mkdir /tmp/test_dir
echo "some output to STDOUT"
touch /tmp/test_dir/new_file
```

how can I highlight and execute it in vim?
I have tried

- `v`, select target text, `:`

which gives a prompt with `:'<, '>`

then tried `:! w`

but its not working properly.
I dont need to write the STDOUT of the shell commands to a file or anything, but I would like to be able to at least see the output.

Comment: There is a Vim module called QuickRun that can do the same thing and give you the result in a split. It can execute the entire buffer or only part of it. https://github.com/thinca/vim-quickrun/blob/master/doc/quickrun.txt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the answer of pacholik, you can extrapolate:

in visual mode, hit `:` and write `w !bash`

so that your whole command is `:'<,'>w !bash`

You will get the output as a result (but it won't change the file

If you remove the `w` , it will instead replace the line by the output of the buffer.

I have for example mapped <kbd>r</kbd> to "run command" in visual mode.

Like this:

```
vnoremap r :w !bash<cr>
```

I also have this in normal mode (to run the current line), with <kbd>yr</kbd> (you run)

```
nnoremap yr :.w !bash<cr>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to add a mapping

Answer (score 0):

You can use Quickrun plugin : http://vimawesome.com/plugin/quickrun-vim

It can run many languages on the fly (bash, python, c++...), and you can run only a selected area.

Everything you need is :

- Set the filetype of your file (normally it's automatically detected, unless you created a new file, in this case just do for example : `:set ft=sh` for `bash`)
- Select a part of your file with <kbd>V</kbd>.
- Run `:'<,'>QuickRun`

The output opens in a new window.
You can tweak the plugin on many points, see the help.